# visual evidence of a world-view in dislocated shards

Tags: meaning-in-context

1. What does "jagged Lines" imply here?
2. Does "visual evidence of a world-view in dislocated shards" mean that all these images, that the writer can remember of the world war scenes, are only a few parts of a larger world-view?

Context:

> Far more immediate to the constituencies of both art and science was the First World War and, if any imagery predominates for me, it is that of the **jagged lines**, the upheaval of mud and the dismembered bodies of the trenches, **visual evidence of a world-view in dislocated shards**.
>
> — [*Art and Science*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xCkBAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=the+upheaval+of+mud+and+the+dismembered+bodies+of+the+trenches&source=bl&ots=E_caKnMa1z&sig=X4wEmh8dbAtfTBdxA6i9szDcd2g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAGoVChMImqS6xK3zxgIVAcuACh1i4wWj#v=onepage&q=the%20upheaval%20of%20mud%20and%20the%20dismembered%20bodies%20of%20the%20trenches&f=false) by Sian Ede

Comment: 1. Nothing you can discern from the text.  2. Impossible to tell.  Remember that Ede knows nothing of the science and mathematics she discusses, so it's best not to trust her knowledge of World War I.  She says, "for me."  This is a private meditation.  You have no access to her meaning.

Comment: In the photos from World War I that I've seen, the most vividly jagged lines are supplied by the broken remnants of trees in wooded areas after intensive bombardment.

Answer (score 1):

**jagged lines**

I presume 'jagged lines' refers to the appearance of the trenches.

>
>
[image]

**visual evidence of a world-view in dislocated shards**

This is a most peculiar phrase. It tries to say that the visual impact of the trenches is evocative of the fragmented world-view of the time.

Does that help? If not I'll explain more fully.

Comment: Ah, you presume.  To be fair that's all you or anyone else can do.  Perhaps Ede has seen your diagram with its crisp and jagged lines.  It's unlikely that's what the combatants saw from the actual trenches, particularly after a hard rain.   Certainly the Great War shattered empires along with the lives of combatants and the world views of survivors, but the trenches were a monotony.  This "visual impact" is a private conjuring of the author's mind's eye.

Comment: Here's a real photo of the jagged lines of the trenches: http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/03/14/1394818301817_Image_galleryImage_Collect_aerial_photos_cap.JPG It is definitely not certain that that is what the writer is referring to but it is what comes to my mind when I think of the jagged lines of the first world war.

Comment: Yep, they look pretty jagged to me. Maybe the author did actually know how the trenches were shaped.

Comment: @deadrat As the photo shows, chasly's diagram doesn't do the jaggedness of the lines justice. It was very noticeable. If hard rain removed the jaggedness then it wasn't jagged enough: they were a deliberate feature to limit the casualties the shrapnel from a single shell could inflict if it landed in a trench.

Comment: @Avon It's very noticeable *on the diagrams,* which, as i understand it, was to prevent flanking attacks.  This neatness didn't survive in the actual trenches and would hardly be noticeable to the occupying combatants.  Ede's prose combines this supposed jaggedness with the mud and dismembered bodies of the trenches and turns the whole mess into shards of *Weltanschauungen*  I suppose it means something to her, but it's not possible to figure out what from her prose.

Comment: @deadrat No it wasn't to prevent flanking attacks (there were no flanks: the trenches stretched for hundreds of miles). It was to prevent a single artillery shell sending shrapnel along hundreds of metres of straight trenches and killing and wounding hundreds of men. The jaggedness is far more noticeable in the photo I linked to above: a nearly 90 degree angle every few metres.

Comment: @deadrat Even if it weren’t noticed by the actual combatants, Ede is describing the _imagery_ that is predominant to _her_. She’s not 120 years old and wasn’t there—her imagery may very well be based on photos like the one Avon linked to above. The combatants are, in this context, irrelevant. (Incidentally, I would say it definitely was noticed by the combatans—my great-grandfather told stories from WWI where he was a soldier, and they left me, too, with a mental image of almost labyrinthine, zigzagging trenches and evoking a feeling of isolation and discontinuity in the soldiers.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "Predominant" isn't quite the right word.  Ede is describing imagery that's *private* to her, and her ignorance of the subjects she writes about and her idiosyncratic language make the meaning of most of her prose inaccessible.  Maybe your great-grandfather evoked a feeling of isolation in you.  Perhaps that's because he was never in a bunched charge across no-man's land into machine-gun fire.  Probably so, since he returned to tell the tale.  Perhaps your feeling of isolation is related to shards of world views too.

Comment: @deadrat Some people did make that charge and survive (e.g. Arthur Barraclough did it six times). Janus's great-grandfather may well have. I don't see why you would speculate about that. The "predominant" experience of the war for them may well have been the months on end in trenches rather than a few minutes of charging into machine guns and for those that didn't go over the top it certainly would have been.

Comment: @Avon It was just a guess.  See the "perhaps" and the "probably"?  And entirely tangential to my point, which was that trench warfare in the first world war wasn't a physically "lonely" experience.  It was masses of men either thrown against high-velocity weaponry.  This isn't to say that JBJ's "feeling" of isolation is invalid, just that it isn't going to make much sense juxtaposed to shards of world views a la  Ede.  Her language is nearly private and not amenable to the usual interpretive tactics.

Comment: @deadrat I agree that it is tangential and that we are speculating as to what Ede meant. But we are free to do that considering that the word 'jagged' does evoke things in our minds about the First World War. Whereas to speculate (guess if you prefer) about JBJ's great-grandfather's experiences: I think that could be seen as quite disrespectful. I took JBJ to be referring to an isolation of the soldiers (collectively) from their families and friends as well as, perhaps, sometimes, the individual alone at night with nothing but the sound of artillery for company.

Comment: @Avon You "took JBJ to be referring to"?  I rest my case.  And, yes, you're "free" to make any interpretation you want.  What makes you think I'm trying to stop you, including your making the absurd "interpretation" that I'm being disrespectful to JBJ's great-grandfather?

Comment: @deadrat Hang on! You said "Perhaps that's because he was never in a bunched charge across no-man's land into machine-gun fire." That is the speculation that I think is beneath you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26210/discussion-between-deadrat-and-avon).

Answer (score 1):

> Far more immediate to the constituencies of both art and science was
>   the First World War and, if any imagery predominates for me, it is
>   that of the jagged lines, the upheaval of mud and the dismembered
>   bodies of the trenches, visual evidence of a world-view in dislocated
>   shards.

It is clear that these  obfuscatory and polysyllabic maunderings, interspersed with scarcely concealed platitudinous rhetoric, are committed to the page by this author in the vain hope that we will mistake both her verbiosity  and verbal evasion for real mental acuity. For me her writings evoke an image of yellowing pages lifting and drifting in a chaotic vortex that that knows neither its source nor its destination. In other words, it's bullshit.

Comment: From what I have seen from the questions about her book on this site, I am inclined to agree but feel obliged to caution that these are a very few short quotes selected specifically because of their ambiguity. I dare say many estimable publications would also look like polysyllabic maunderings if only their most unclear and opinionated passages were looked at.

Comment: Well I can only comment on what is put before me. However I admit I have a thing about these arty-farty types. They are usually frustrated practitioners who ended going into criticism or curation through lack of talent. The nonsense they spout is exceeded only by fashion writers who, in my opinion, should mostly be shot on sight. Apart from that, I love them all!

Comment: Indeed and I have commented on other questions about this book about what nonsense she seems to be talking. But coming to quite so scathing conclusions about the author from these few samples is a little unfair. That said, that she may well be as genuine and informative as the Marketing Department of the Sirius Cybernetics Corporation is a distinct possibility from what I have seen so far.

Comment: @Avon - Haha! Very g'd.

Comment: @Avon "few short quotes."  Nah, it's all like that.  And by all, I mean all of the writing in "cultural" theory.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I'm not sure of your last sentence.  Did you mean "execretory extrusions of certain members of a bovine species"?

Answer (score -1):

> a world-view in dislocated shards

is an idea or phrase someone exposed to the esoteric thought of Qabalah would tend to use.

Qabalah was instituted by ancient rabbis to study and derationalize the book of Ezekiel and to align its ideas with the rest of the Bible. It is said that the book of Ezekiel would have been rejected from the canon of the Bible - but fortunately due to the derationalization proffered by Qabalah. Somehow, the regimen was caught on by people not interested in the book of Ezekiel. Therefore, there is difference between actual biblical Qabalah regimen versus voodooistic Kabbalah.

In one of fields of studies/meditation of Qabalah is to reason why a good G'd would allow cruelty, conflict, disaster and catastrophe to inflict the world and humankind.

The Qabalah conclusion was that G'd had completed creating the cosmos, but the cosmos is not completed. Humankind is to be as G'd, to takeover from G'd the completion of the Universe. Humankind is to be as the reciprocal counterpart of G'd in the creation of the Universe. This is reflected in Psalm 8 (verse 2 or 3), stating that humankind is nearly G'd, just a little lesser, except that English/Greek translations could not accept that idea and mistranslated it as "humankind being lesser than angels".

A well-known visual allegory (among those pursuant in Qabalah) is the cosmos was created like an exploding clay bottle, into a huge amount of rough and jagged shards. It is now the task of humankind to use our creative abilities to connect/repair/improve (תקן) those shards into the finality of a Universe.

If I were an author (who has had exposure to Qabalah of some sort) trying to wade thro the pains and senselessness of war, I too would see it as part of the early journey of humankind to connect the shards, except that the lines of connection is currently jagged and rough - a sign of the still immature ability of a humankind who will finally perfect the efforts to complete the creation of the world.

I too would rationalize (or derationalize) by seeing the evil of war, not thro the lens of good vs evil, but as a visual evidence of the Evolutionary process proffered by Qabalah.

OTOH, if I were an author with prior exposure to Qabalah but critical of the existence of a supernatural omnipotent, I would use it as a sarcasm to question - is this what you mean by reconnecting the shards, dear non-existent god?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Yyu know that this does  provide a view into the mind of the author, and hence points to the intended meaning of the phrases in question. You may dislike the idea or to think the author could have deliberately coded a message to protest the beauty of cruelty, to a select audience which may not include you.

Comment: @BlessedGeek For all the text that you wrote, I still have no idea what the phrase in question is supposed to mean.  Therefore I cannot see this as a proper answer.